# rsync: --delete-during --backup-dir=PATH --backup doesn't backup directories that are deleted to make way for files

Tags: rsync

When running rsync with the `--backup` `--delete-during` and `--backup-dir=PATH` options, only files that are deleted are backed up, but directories are not if those directories were empty at the time they were deleted.  I can't see an option that specifies directories should not be pruned from backup when being deleted.

Example:

```
mkdir /tmp/test_rsync_delete
cd /tmp/test_rsync_delete
mkdir -p a/a/a/a/a
ln -s . a/b

mkdir -p b/a/a
ln -s a/a b/a
touch b/a/a/a

mkdir c
mkdir backup

rsync -avi --delete-during --backup --backup-dir=backup a/ c/
find backup/ -exec ls -ldi {} \;
# Should be empty

rsync -avi --delete-during --backup --backup-dir=backup b/ c/
find backup/ -exec ls -ldi {} \;
# Will be missing the directory that was deleted to make way for the file.
```

*Update*

As per the above example, when you run it, you will notice that the empty directories were pruned/removed by the --delete option.  However, the same directories were not backed up in the directory specified by the --backup-dir option.  It's not necessarily the directories that are important, but the permissions and ownership that are important.  If rsync fails when running in batch mode (`--read-batch`) then you need to be able to roll back by restoring the system to its previous state.  If directories are not being backed up, then it's not really creating a reliable point from which to restore to - it will potentially be missing some directories.

So why does the `--backup` family of options not backup empty directories when they are going to be pruned by the `--delete` family of options?

Comment: What exactly is your question now?

Comment: Why when using '--backup' family of options does rsync not 'backup' empty directories that will be pruned by the '--delete' family of options?

Comment: The above steps fail here: `ln -s a/a b/a`
`ln: failed to create symbolic link 'b/a/a': File exists`

Comment: I can't even remember why I needed that symlink in the b directory.  Anyway, its name isn't important, just specify the target as `b/b` instead of `b/a`.  It's only important that a file exists where previously there wasn't one.

Answer (score -3):

This is not an answer to the specific question, but probably the answer to, what others were searching for, ending up here:

Just for info: this is what I was searching for when I found this question:

```
rsync -av --delete-after src dest
```

***-av*** The "-a" means **archive**.  This will preserve symlinks, permissions, timestamps, group/owners, and will be recursive. The "v" makes the job **verbose**.  This won't be necessary, but you can see what's happening with the rsync so you know if you've done something wrong.
***--delete-after*** Will tell rsync to compare the destination against the source and delete any extraneous files after the rsync has completed.  This is a dangerous option, so use with caution.

Comment: But I don't see the relation to the question I asked.  I am asking why the --backup family of options doesn't backup empty directories when they are going to be pruned by the --delete family of options.